# String to Array Convert in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have show data from database. Like TIME

```
06:58
12:04 
12:54
16:02
```

now i want to convert this record to array function
i wanna calculate time. 
i have 4 entry in one (TIME) Column. 
how to convert this record to array

```
    06:58  // Like $String[0]  this is Join time
    12:04  // Like $String[1] this is leave time
    12:54  // Like $String[2] Join Time
    16:02  // Like $String[3] Leave Time.
```

i wanna select Time one by one for Calculation

```
$date = '05.01.2015';
$data = data($conn);

if(!empty($data)){
    foreach($data as $d){
         $p_n = $d['Pers_No'];  
         $bydate = bydate($conn, $p_n, $date);
            if(!empty($bydate)){
                foreach($bydate as $bd){
                $bddate = $bd['Zeit'];
                $bdpers = $bd['Pers_No'];
            //      echo $bdpers.' - ';
                if($bdpers == $p_n){

                        $hr = $bddate.'<br>';

                        echo $hr; // Here showing record.
                        /*
                        Like: 
                        06:58
                        12:04
                        12:54
                        16:02
                         */

                    } 

                }
                echo '<hr>';
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: @treegarden i can't understand how i convert $hr to array for select time.

Comment: when you are getting it from database than only you need to loop for each row. At that time only you can do your calculations. No need to loop it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are doing with your sample code, but...

Here are three generic ways to make an array.

```
foreach($record['time'] as $key => $time){
  $string[] = $time
}
```

---

```
$string = array('06:58','12:04','12:54','16:02');
```

---

```
$string[] = '06:58';
$string[] = '12:04';
$string[] = '12:54';
$string[] = '16:02';
```

Comment: Thanks. `$string = array();
    foreach($bydate as $key => $time){
     $string[] = $time['Zeit']; 
    }
    $timein = $string[0];
    $timeout = $string[1];` work now

Answer (score 0):

```
$String = array();
if($bdpers == $p_n){
    array_push($String, $bddate);
}
var_dump($String);
```

Declare an array variable before the `echo` loop, instead of just `echo` the variables, add them into the array using `array_push`. After the loop you can use your new array.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: My bad Jay Blanchard.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks all -
>   This code have solved my problem

```
$string = array();
    foreach($bydate as $key => $time){
        $string[] = $time['Zeit']; 
    }
        $timein = $string[0];
        $timeout = $string[1];
```